# I am confused about the drake simulate

Tags: drake

I am confused about the DRAKE simulate. Do you need to use the simulate class with a real robot arm?
What does drake simulate do?

Answer (score 0):

Drake's [Simulator](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_simulator.html) class is used for advancing time for a Drake System. The System may contain a simulated robot, or may communicate directly with a real robot. Please consider looking through the overview material on the [Drake web site](https://drake.mit.edu/) and at some of the examples that come with Drake to get the big picture.